# I am having a class not found exception for an applet I'm trying to put in a web page. Think it might be directory related

Tags: applet

I have the java stuff in its own folder and have the main class some folders down from the main html.

The folder right below the html code is called "java", the folder inside of "java" that next needs to be used is called "churcheventcalendar".  There is one in "churcheventcalendar" called "churchevents".  There is one in "churchevents" called "main".  Inside of "main", there is a class file called "EventsApplet".

Also, my jar file is inside of "churcheventscalendar".   I have heard that the applet tag is deprecated in html 5 so I tried looking up what to do online.  It recommended that I use an embed tag.  I tried what they had, altering it to make it fit.

I did hear somewhere else, while trying to find the problem  that perhaps I shouldn't have the .class in the "code" attribute, but removing it didn't solve the problem, so I put it back.

There are some other issues that might be causing it.  I originally had the java file in another folder, but I compiled it in the new folder where I copied it to, so that shouldn't be it.  I even remade the jar file there.  Still nothing.

I still think it's a directory issue or something that, as a novice, I don't see.

Here's what I have for the embed code:

[code]

```
<embed id="testapplet"  style="border: 1px solid black;"
       type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
       width="256" height="256" 
       archive="./java/churcheventscalendar/churcheventcalendar.jar"
       code="./java/churcheventcalendar/churchevents/main/EventsApplet.class" />
```

[/code]

It is showing an error message type thing in red where the applet should be.  When I click it, it shows a dialog that says:

"ClassNotFoundException" and it says

"..java.churcheventcalendar.churchevents.main.EventsApplet.class"

When I click "Details", it says:

[code]

```
Java Plug-in 11.25.2.18
Using JRE version 1.8.0_25-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Patriot Mongoose
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

[/code]

I should add that the html files are in "C:/Users/Patriot Mongoose/Documents/sprbc" directory as the main root directory where all the web stuff is.   The java folder and subsequent lower folders are in that directory.   Also, when I created the jar file in JGrasp, as the thing was an applet, there was no main class, so to speak, to select from when creating it.  Normally there is, but that's because I've pretty much always made offline Java GUIs before and hence there was a class with a main method.

The html file where the applet is being called at is in the "sprbc" folder and is called "home.html".

So now you know where the files are at and might be able to see if it's a directory error.

Do you see what I could be doing wrong?   Is it what I'm putting under the code attriubte or is it what I'm putting under the archive attribute or is it both and a directory error?   Could it even be because I have AdBlockPlus running?   Could it be my value under the version attribute?  (That one said 1.6, like where I copied the example from, but the thing under details said it was JRE 1.8.something.   I did change that to 1.8 to see if anything happened, but it's still busted.  On the other hand, I thought I'd still ask.)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Ok, got help on Java Programming Forums.  However, now security is blocking my applet.  It's only a local applet.  I have turned off AdBlock Plus (didn't help, so I turned that back on.)

I have gone to the Java Control Panel and it is already set to "High" like it should be.   I have added the local files to the blocking exceptions.  Still not working.

How do you get it to accept an uncertified applet?

Comment: I still can't find out what's wrong.  I'm looking online to see examples.  It appears to be right, but it's not.

Comment: I have also asked for help here:  http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/whats-wrong-my-code/40324-applet-having-classnotfoundexception.html#post160302

Comment: I think I got it.  The only issue left is why Chrome is always demanding permission for every applet.   It's a pain.  (And will no doubt be for users too.)